# Waiting for a specific operation - Android

Tags: java, android, background, task, wait

I want to wait for a specific operation to complete before continuing the code flow.
Something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

downloadSomeFiles(); // I want to wait for this operation to finish
Log.d("Download", "Download Complete") //This should run After downloading completed
}
```

However downloading takes some time and I always end up getting NullPointerException because downloading wasn't completed.
Assume we don't know how long we must wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long running operations on the main thread are never a good idea, as they block the User Interface.

If you want to do this while the application is running, consider using methods from `java.util.concurrent` package (or coroutines if you want to switch to Kotlin). `AsyncTask` became deprecated.
Here is a guide: https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrency

If you want your download to execute in the background even if your application is closed, consider using a `Service`: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Answer (score 1):

I could only suggest using Asyntask<>

Here's a sample approach for you to understand.
I just wanna comment this but I don't have enough reputation to do it.

```
AsyncTask<String, String, String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       // ... Show a Progress Dialog or anything you want just to indicate that you 
       // ... are downloading ...
   }

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
       super.onProgressUpdate(values);
   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
       // ... Do Downloading or anything
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
       super.onPostExecute(s);

       // Post any codes to be followed here ...
       Log.d("Download", "Download Complete")
   }
}

asynTask.execute();
```

Comment: I read this on android documentation. But it's depracated now.

Answer (score 1):

Create a response callback like so:

```
public interface ResponseCallback {
        void onDownload();
}
```

Then in your method

```
downloadSomeFiles(ResponseCallback responsecallback) {
    //Download files
    responsecallback.onDownload(); //Trigger it
}
```

Then call it

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

downloadSomeFiles(new ResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDownload() {
                Log.d("Download", "Download Complete");
            }
});
```